# SQL Syntax with ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: android, mysql, sql

Im creaing an android app and I am using MySQL.

The MySQL table look like

[image: this]

I want to get the user's rank by his qa, if I want to get Kenig's rank I will get 1 because he has the most qa (1060) and if I want to get Dyrus's rank I will get 3 because he has the lowest qa etc..

I looked all over the internet for a query to do that and this is the result

```
SELECT ip,name,qa,ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY qa) AS Number FROM users ORDER BY qa;
```

But when I try to run this line I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(ORDER BY qa) AS Number FROM users ORDER BY id' at line 12

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is not available in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same result with this construct:

```
set @num=0;

select name, rank FROM (
  SELECT 
    ip,
    name,
    qa,
    @num := @num + 1  as rank
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM world.test ORDER BY qa DESC
  ) A
) B  WHERE name = 'Kenig';
```